# Why is getStaticProps() an asynchronous function in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Why is `getStaticProps()` an asynchronous function in Next.js? As I understand it, an async function is one offloaded from the main thread while it executes. This stops the main thread from being unnecessarily held up by functions that can take a while (ex. fetching from a database).

`getStaticProps()` is executed at build time and therefore doesn't impact the main thread rendering the page in Next.js. I was therefore wondering why it's an asynchronous function. Is this so it doesn't block execution while the application is being built? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> As I understand it, an async function is one offloaded from the main thread while it executes.

You misunderstand. `async` is syntactical sugar for a function that returns a Promise. It's not run on a separate thread, and indeed, if you have a very long synchronous function, `async` functions won't get run.

> I was therefore wondering why it's an asynchronous function.

Because it may well need to do asynchronous calls such as getting data from an external source, as [e.g. this official example shows](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-props#using-getstaticprops-to-fetch-data-from-a-cms).

If it wasn't an `async` function, it would need to asynchronicity via a callback (which is quite outmoded) to be able to return data after an asynchronous call.

> Does it execute in a separate thread on the server while the application is being built?

Likely not (considering Node.js is single-threaded).

Comment: My mistake, I meant why is it an asynchronous function not an `async`. Your answer helped illuminate the solution because I looked at the docs for clarification and they state that `Exporting a function called getStaticProps() will pre-render a page at build time using the props returned from the function`. This makes me pretty confident that `getStaticProps()` itself is not asynchronous by nature the way `fetch` is, it merely contains asynchronous function calls.

Comment: Because if it was synchronous, it couldn't do asynchronous calls such as network calls.

Comment: There's no difference in the "nature of asynchronicity" between `fetch` and `getStaticProps`.

Comment: Would it not be possible for `getStaticProps` to execute synchronously if it simple injected dummy data into the pre-render?

Comment: Well, with how `async` functions work, if your `getStaticProps` has no `await` in it, it will internally execute synchronously.

Comment: Yes, that's all I was saying. Without `async/await` syntax, `getStaticProps()` will execute synchronously while, as I understand it, `fetch()` is inherently asynchronous because it is offloaded onto the browser API while the main thread executes.